# Display configuration files in /etc that contain numbers in their names (using grep)

Tags: bash, grep

Task (12) from [here.](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_05.html)

Using **grep** I could solve this task as following:

```
grep --no-message -l [[:alnum:]] /etc/* | grep [[:digit:]]
```

Similar results were obtained:

```
ls -o /etc/ | grep ^- | awk '{print $8}' | grep [[:digit:]]
```

But I want to read all files under each directory, recursively. And this is what I could do:

```
grep --no-message -lR [[:alnum:]] /etc/* | grep [[:digit:]]
```

Also how this task can be solved today? Is this a correct way? What kind of additional solutions you can offer to solve this task?

Comment: Do you want to search file content or file names?

Comment: I want to search for file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grisha and Andrey have given perfect answers.  However, if you are looking for a solution that does use `grep`, here it is.

```
while read -r filepath; do
  # grep for digits in the basename so that we choose only those
  # files that have a digit in them, not in any parent directory name
  if grep -q '[[:digit:]]' <<< "$(basename $filepath)"; then
    echo "$filepath"
  fi
done < <(find /etc -type f -print)
```

It's not efficient at all.

Comment: @kurgulus  please check my 2nd answer

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using to `grep` just to get file names. i.e. instead of what I think you are trying to do with

```
grep --no-message -l [[:alnum:]] /etc/*
```

You can just do

```
echo /etc/*
```

Since the goal is to list files with numbers, you can use a glob like:

```
echo /etc/*[[:digit:]]*
```

If you want to do this recursively you can do it in bash like:

```
shopt -s globstar
echo /etc/**/*[[:digit:]]*
```

Or you can use `find`:

```
find /etc -name '*[[:digit:]]*'
```

Comment: Note that `echo` lists all files on a single line unlike `find` which puts a newline in between.  Pipe `echo` output to `xargs -nX` to see the output in X columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find`:

```
find /etc -type f -name \*[[:digit:]]\*
```

Please note that this command lists only files with digits in *names*, not the full paths. For the latter use a different filter:

```
find /etc -type f -path \*[[:digit:]]\*
```

Answer (score 0):

If the task is to have a pure `grep` solution, then here it is:

```
grep -laR . /etc | grep '^.*/[^/]*[[:digit:]][^/]*$'
```

The regular expression:

1. `^...$` cover the full line;
2. `.*/[^/]*...[^/]*` look only for the file name.